# MySQL Join multiple rows in one column with condition

Tags: mysql

## Tables

#### Person

```
ID|NAME |SURNAME
1 |James|Smith
2 |Jack |Sparrow
```

#### PeopleDepartment

```
IDPERSON|IDDEPARTMENT
1       |1
1       |2
2       |2
```

#### Department

```
ID|NAME
1 |customer_service
2 |store
```

## Problem

What I need to do is select people and its departments, filtering by one or more departments. Now I'm able to select all the people and their departments, but I can't filter the results by departments name:

```
SELECT person.name, person.surname, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct department.name SEPARATOR ', ') as departments
LEFT JOIN peopledepartment ON person.id=department.idperson
INNER JOIN department ON peopledepartment.iddepartment=department.id
```

And the output with that query is:

```
NAME |SURNAME|DEPARTMENTS
James|Smith  |customer_service, store
Jack |Sparrow|store
```

I need to filter that result by department.name='customer_service', so the result is only:

```
NAME |SURNAME|DEPARTMENTS
James|Smith  |customer_service, store
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT p.name, p.surname,
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct d.name SEPARATOR ', ') as departments
FROM person p INNER JOIN
     peopledepartment pd
     ON p.id = pd.idperson INNER JOIN
     department d
     ON pd.iddepartment = d.id
GROUP BY p.name, p.surname
HAVING SUM(d.name = 'customer_service') > 0;
```

Notes:

- The `distinct` is probably not necessary in `group_concat()`.
- Use table aliases.  These make it easier to write and read the query.
- You seem to have left out the `from` clause in your question.
- The `having` clause counts the number of rows that match the given department.  The `> 0` means that at least one such match exists.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly, and yes, I forgot to write the FROM and GROUP BY when I copied the query.